# Styling Overlay play button inside video element shadowRoot

Tags: html, css, html5-video, hls.js

I am trying to change image of overlay play button to different one on android chrome. I am able to inspect the image in developer tool.

I am also able to add css to its parent element like ..

```
`video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-play-button {
 //any css}`
```

but not to the child element where I wanted.. The element where I want my css is - -internal-media-controls-overlay-play-button-internal

I tried

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-play-button::-internal-media-controls-overlay-play-button-internal {
}
```

or

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-play-button div[pseudo="-internal-media-controls-overlay-play-button-internal"] {
}
```

but it did not work.. Here is the my dev tool image for better clarification
[image: Dev Tool Image]

Any help would highly be appreciated.. Thanks..